# PHP Soap passing array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, soap, wsdl

My method:

```
/**
 * @param \LeosEbayGateway\Soap\Model\Apigw\SkuQty $changeStocksBySkus[]
 */
public function change_stocks_by_skus(array $changeStocksBySkus)
{
    var_dump($changeStocksBySkus);
    die();
}
```

SoapUI

Input:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ind="http://ebay/index.php">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ind:change_stocks_by_skus>
         <changeStocksBySkus>
            <sku>1</sku>
            <qty>2</qty>
         </changeStocksBySkus>
         <changeStocksBySkus>
            <sku>3</sku>
            <qty>4</qty>
         </changeStocksBySkus>
      </ind:change_stocks_by_skus>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Output is:

```
object(stdClass)#236 (2) {
  ["sku"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

I'm passing array of values, but Output is only 1 object not array, why ?

Actions:

```
public function wsdlAction(Request $request)
{
    $autodiscover = new \Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover->setClass('\\LeosEbayGateway\\Soap\\Service\\SoapServerService');
    $autodiscover->setUri('http://' .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

    return new Response($autodiscover->toXml(), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/xml']);
}

public function apiAction(Request $request)
{
    $options = array(
        'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'uri'           => 'http://localhost:8000/api/wsdl',
    );

    $server = new \Zend\Soap\Server(null, $options);
    $server->setObject(new SoapServerService());
    $server->handle();
}
```

SoapServerService.php

```
<?

namespace test\Soap\Service;


class SoapServerService {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @var Application
     */
    private $application;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param \test\Soap\Model\Apigw\SkuQty $changeStocksBySkus[]
     */
    public function change_stocks_by_skus(array $changeStocksBySkus)
    {
        if(!is_array($changeStocksBySkus)) {
            throw $this->toSoapFault("changeStocksBySkus param is not array!");
        }

        try {
            return (new SoapServiceProducts())->ChangeStocksBySkus($changeStocksBySkus);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $this->toSoapFault($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Because looking at the XML, the `sku` 9 is the only one changed. It is duplicated in the XML.

Comment: @mvbrakel no, I'm edit example same results

Comment: Could you please provide the PHP from where it calls the function `change_stocks_by_skus`. Seems like the selector there is missing functionality for multiple nodes of the same name

Comment: Calling from soapUI software.

Comment: But we are fixing a piece of PHP right? Hardly think that SoapUI calls `change_stocks_by_skus`. I understand that the XML is provided via the use of SoapUI

Comment: @mvbrakel I'm updatet post, see now

Comment: Still no code visible that parses the XML and leads to a call of `change_stocks_by_skus`

Comment: Zend Soap server parsing XML from my class

Comment: Please include SoapServerService then....

Comment: Could you try changing the `$server = new \Zend\Soap\Server(null, $options);` to `$server = new \Zend\Soap\Server('http://localhost:8000/api/wsdl', array());` ? At the moment it starts in non-wsdl mode.. perhaps interfering with the definitions in the autodiscover

Comment: Same, nothing changes ...

Comment: I must say i am out of quick options at the moment then. I do not have the time to trace the Zend\Soap\Server::handle() at the moment. Hope someone else can help you!

Comment: After some digging it seems to boil back to the core `\SoapServer::handle` from PHP. Which always passes the body as a `stdObj`. Solution would be to wrap the requested data in an extra node like for example `changeStocksBySkusCollection`.

Comment: In what method I cant wrap requested data, I think in change_stocks_by_skus is inpossible ..